# Azure Sphere code refuses to compile. Gives error "undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation

The code below refuses to compile. I get an error `"undefined
 reference to 'curl_easy_init'` because it can't find the function. This
 is despite triple checking a declaration of the file is present in the
 `easy.h` file `CURL_EXTERN CURL *curl_easy_init(void);`

`The easy.h` file is included in `main.c` as a `#include`. The function is
quite clearly also included in the Solution Explorer" pane which lists
all the library files and functions the SDK has included for use.

When I hover over `curl_easy_init()`, it pops up a help dialog ie it
recognises the file. This tells me the IDE can find it.

```
 Compile error dump below 1>------ Build started: Project: My Learning,
 Configuration: Debug ARM ------ 1>/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Azure
 Sphere SDK/Sysroots/2/tools/gcc/real-ld.exe: obj\ARM\Debug\main.o: in
 function `main': 1>\Dropbox\EBD\Clients\My\Interface
 Box\Development\Firmware\My Learning/main.c:32: undefined reference to
 `curl_easy_init' 1>collect2.exe : error : ld returned 1 exit status
 1>Done building project "My Learning.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
 ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I can't understand why it can't find the file??? It's 2 lines of code!!!

```
   include <stdbool.h>
   #include <errno.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <time.h>
   #include <stdio.h>

   #include <applibs/log.h>
   #include <applibs/gpio.h>
   #include <curl/curl.h>
   #include <curl/easy.h>

   int main(void)
   {
       CURL* curl;
       curl = curl_easy_init();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please doublecheck your compiler invocation command: perhaps you should link `libcurl`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!! It worked. I wasn't sure what you meant but then I looked up the Azure Sphere documentation and worked it out. Thanks for the tipoff.

The fix is to open the Property Page->Linker->Input then add ;curl at the end of line "Library Dependencies". That does it

Comment: Please consider to accept and upvote the answer that was helpful to you.